# The shortest distance between multiple points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So i want to calculate distance between my start point and multiple points, than display the shortest route to this point,but it show me always the last point. this is my distanceCal function it works fine :

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1);  // deg2rad below
var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
var a =
  Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
  Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
  Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
;
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
var d = R * c; // Distance in km
return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
 return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
}
```

and this is my points latt/long :

```
var dist = [
  [35.733972, -5.881999],
  [ 35.734077, -5.881033],
  [ 35.736898, -5.877771],
  [35.738396, -5.875154]
  ];
```

then my script to display directions :

```
function calcRoute() {
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(35.728329, -5.882750);
for (var i = 0; i < dist.length; i++)
{
    var dis = dist[i];
    //here i need something to choose the shortest route
    var min = Math.min(getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(35.728329, -5.882750, dis[0], dis[1]));
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(dis[0], dis[1]);
}
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
});

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', getMap);
```

so please if someone have any idea or solution i will be very appreciate.

Comment: Yes, you forgot to choose and write to `end` in every loop turn. And your getting `Math.min` from one value?

Comment: Are you essentially asking us to solve the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

Comment: @deceze no i don't i have just a mistake in my loop

Comment: I made the experience that google Distance matrix is alot faster than your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses  Googles [**geometry**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) library to calculate distances between points.The distances are stored in an array and then parsed to find minimum distance .

I have changed the array from dist[] to coords[] as we need an array to hold distances dist[].

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var coords = [
  [35.733972, -5.881999],
  [35.734077, -5.881033],
  [35.736898, -5.877771],
  [35.738396, -5.875154]
  ];
  var dist = [];//Array to hold distances
   function calcRoute() { {
      var start = new google.maps.LatLng(35.728329, -5.882750);
      for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i][0],coords[i][1]);
        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(start, point);
        dist.push(distance);
       }  
        var test = dist[0];
   var index = 0;
   for (var i = 1; i < dist.length; i++){
        if(dist[i] < test){
            test = dist[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
   var end = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[index][0],coords[index][1]);

       // Apply the rest of your code here
```

Comment: thanks david the code is excellent but this line is wrong            **var end = new google.maps.LatLng(sortArray[0][0],sortArray[0][1]);**  when i change it to sortArray[0],sortArray[1] i get array of distances

Comment: I will change last line You are correct I tested everything except the last line

Comment: @Mohammadov I have modified Answer to provide solution

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use optimizeWaypoints:true in your [DirectionsServiceRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest):

> optimizeWaypoints | boolean | If set to true, the DirectionService will attempt to re-order the supplied intermediate waypoints to minimize overall cost of the route. If waypoints are optimized, inspect DirectionsRoute.waypoint_order in the response to determine the new ordering.

The [DirectionsResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult)

Each [leg of each route](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsLeg) returned includes distance and duration information.