# Search a city using google map

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a google map to show location in find search box ([from that link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead)) which is working fine:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl',function($scope, $http) {

$scope.getLocation = function(val) { 
   return $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
    params: {
    address: val,
    sensor: false
   }
}).then(function(response){
return response.data.results.map(function(item){
return item.formatted_address;
});
});
};

<h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
<pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)"     typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
<i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
<div ng-show="noResults">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
</div>
```

I would like to know if possible to show my custom city near the search entry ?
Let's say I have bbCity, aaCity, ccCity and when a user types bb, her/him gets the nearest one (bbCity).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a right way but I solved it by adding the answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122381/the-shortest-distance-between-multiple-points).

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl',function($scope, $http) {

 // Predefined areas
    var predefinedLocations = [[48,68435270497298,4,39454410970211, 'city 1'],[48,33375503137806,5,616522543132305, 'city 2']];
$scope.getLocation = function(val) { 
    return $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
                address: val,
                sensor: false
      }
    }).then(function(response){
        return response.data.results.map(function(item){
             // Hold distances
                var distances = [];

                    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(item.geometry.location.lat, item.geometry.location.lng);

                    for (var i = 0; i < predefinedLocations.length; i++)
                    {
                        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(predefinedLocations[i][0],predefinedLocations[i][1]);

                        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(start, point);
                        distances.push(distance);
                    }

                    var firstElement = distances[0];
                var index = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i < distances.length; i++)
                {
                    if(distances[i] < firstElement)
                    {
                        firstElement = distances[i];
                        index = i;
                    }
                }

                    return predefinedLocations[index][2];
    });
  });
};
```